# Python tkinter labels become uncentered after adding another label

Tags: python, tkinter

As a preface to this question, I've tried searching for the issue before, to no avail.

I am trying to make a small login system - the back-end with SQL is working just fine, though the front-end side is not working as intended. My initial code has no issues, everything is centered; after I added just one more label the centering became off for no apparent reason.

Here's the code(do let me know if anything is missing):

```py
def main_window(): #actual login window

    #define constants start

    global root
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Hockey Login System")
    width = 800
    height = 500
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
    y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
    root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
    root.resizable(0, 0)
#alignment related constants

    title_frame = Frame(root, bd=2,  relief=RIDGE)
    title_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
    Form = Frame(root, height=500)
    Form.pack(side=TOP, pady=20)

    #define constants finish

    #login labels placement start

    label_title = Label(title_frame, text="Please log in in order to access Hockey.", font=('arial', 15))
    label_title.pack(fill=X)
    label_username = Label(Form, text="Username", font=('arial', 14), bd=15)
    label_username.grid(row=0, sticky="e")
    label_password = Label(Form, text="Password", font=('arial', 14), bd=15)
    label_password.grid(row=1, sticky="e")
    global label_text
    label_text = Label(Form)
    label_text.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

    #login labels placement finish

    #entry boxes start

    username = Entry(Form, textvariable=USERNAME, font=(14))
    username.grid(row=0, column=1)
    password = Entry(Form, textvariable=PASSWORD, show="*", font=(14))
    password.grid(row=1, column=1)

    #entry boxes finish


    #login & register buttons start

    btn_login = Button(Form, text="Login(will start game if successful)", width=45, command=Login)
    btn_login.grid(pady=25, row=3, columnspan=2)
    btn_login.bind('<Return>', Login)

    btn_register = Button(Form, text="Register with inserted credentials", width=45, command=Register)
    btn_register.grid(pady=25, row=4, columnspan=2)
    btn_register.bind('<Return>', Login)

    #login & register buttons finish

    #copyright/credits start

    label_creation = Label(Form, text="Created using Python, tkinter and SQLite3", font=('arial', 12), bd=15)
    label_creation.grid(pady=25, row=5, sticky="e")

    #copyright/credits finish


    root.mainloop()     #runs window
```

The lines in question are the label_creation variables near the end of the code. This is what the code looks like:

Without label_creation: [(centered)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6vL7.png)

With label_creation: [not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILwwQ.png)

In all, I have been trying to make everything centered but failed horribly, including getting an ungodly amount of errors due to doing both .grid() and .pack().

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example for us to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed defining the `columnspan` argument for your last label, so it tried fitting the whole text inside the single first column, widening it as a result.

```py
label_creation = Label(Form, text="Created using Python, tkinter and SQLite3", font=('arial', 12), bd=15)
label_creation.grid(pady=25, row=5, columnspan=2, sticky="e")
```